# How to query for @ElementCollection attributes using Spring Data JPA query language?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

My code looks like:

```
@Entity
public class A extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKeyColumn(name = "propertyKey")
@Column(name = "propertyValue")
private Map<String, String> properties;


}
```

I use the following query,

```
    @Query("Select a from A a JOIN a.properties vp where vp.propertyValue = ?2 ")
 A findByRequestedSimNumber(String key, String simNumber);
```

When I run the application I got error with such exception:

```
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException:cannot     dereference scalar collection element: propertyValue [Select a from A a JOIN a.properties vp where vp.propertyValue = ?2 ]
```

I am really confused, can't we access the attributes of the mapped table.Please help me to sort the problem.
Thankyou!

Answer (score 4):

In the [repositories deep dive code examples](https://github.com/olivergierke/repositories-deepdive) we do it like this:

The Product entity:

```
@Entity
public class Product extends AbstractEntity {
...

@ElementCollection
    private Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
...
}
```

The repository query method that allows querying for arbitrary product attributes:

```
@Query("select p from Product p where p.attributes[?1] = ?2")
List<Product> findByAttributeAndValue(String attribute, String value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query will have to look like

```
Select a from A a, IN(a.properties) as vp where vp.propertyValue = ?2
```

You cannot just ask for equality in a collection.

If your problem is to access the properties in a given A, they are automatically loaded with the A object, so you only have to

```
A a = <some finder method>
System.out.println(a.properties);
```